# Dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu from 2 different HDDs

Tags: windows, linux

Possible Duplicates:

- [Dual Boot Linux/Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/38024/dual-boot-linux-windows-7)
- [Dual Boot Windows 7 + Linux on 2 separate SDD + Data HDD](https://superuser.com/questions/300417/dual-boot-windows-7-linux-on-2-separate-sdd-data-hdd)

I want to install Ubuntu on a separate hard drive than my current Windows 7, and I want to dual boot either Linux or Windows when I start my PC. Is there any step-by-step instruction on how I can do that.

Comment: another: http://superuser.com/questions/38024/dual-boot-linux-windows-7

Comment: and more: http://superuser.com/questions/786/how-to-dual-boot-home-pc-with-linux-and-windows-7